# Using angular constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, model-view-controller

If I set a few constant in a file like this :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('balrogApp.config', [])
    .constant('balrogConfig', {
        'backend': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/catalog',
        'authenticatedUser': 1
    });
```

How can I access it from a controller ? :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('balrogApp.header', ['balrogApp.config'])
    .controller('headerController', ['balrogConfig', function ($location, Users, balrogConfig) {
        this.usersList = Users.query();

        this.currentUser = balrogConfig.authenticatedUser;
        /* ... */
    }])
```

This way is working for a factory, but not for the controller. So how to import and use properly my constant ?

Also, is there a way to set a constant from a view ?

Basically, I would like to set `authenticatedUser` after the authentication with the proper value (retrieved from a view the input model) and be able to access it from any controller.

Comment: You shouldn't change a constant at runtime.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#constant-recipe

Comment: Well, I don't wanna change it actually, I want to initialize it from a view, it won't change after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't inject the constant properly.

```
['$location', 'Users', 'balrogConfig', function ($location, Users, balrogConfig)
```